# Laboratory Scale beer Production for Microbiology and sensory evaluation

Tags: fermentation, hops, carbonation, techniques, bottle-conditioning

What is the easiest and best way  make opaque beer in the lab? The  beer has to be made in such a way that it will be able to be tasted. Besides using hops what other alternatives could I use for me to increase the bitterness in the beer?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few distinct questions in this, but I can comment on one of your questions:

**Besides using hops what other alternatives could I use for me to increase the bitterness in the beer?**

A number of different wild herbs have been used as bittering agents in beer. Examples of this are scotch broom, mugwort, and yarrow. A quick internet search can reveal a number of different herbal options, but you can also refer to [Sacred and Herbal Healing Beers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0937381667) for herbal mixtures as well. I recently saw an episode of a TV show called "Brew Dogs", in which they brew a hop free beer (Season 1 Episode 6), which is also a good watch.

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on what the desired taste is of the opaque beer (SRM 30). The most potent in color and most flavor neutral dark grain, is Midnight Wheat.

As far as bittering. Use hop extract (hopshot) when utilized in a boil of 45 minutes or longer all traces of flavor and aroma of the original hop is boiled off. It has very little hop profile to start with anyways. It's designed to only add bitterness.